# Data Studio Filter results to rows whose arrays contain two values

Tags: looker-studio

I have a table like this:

| Name | Array |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | [Barks, Furry] |
| Cat | [Purrs, Furry, Other] |
| Broken Duck | [Purrs, Feather] |

When I use a control and select Purrs and Furry, I get all three rows. The desired outcome is to only get the cat row.

Under the hood in BQ Name is a string and Array is actually an `Array<struct<type: string, value:string>>` e.g. `[{'array_element':'Barks'}]` with all `type` values equal to `array_element`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the **CSV Filter Control** [Community Visualisation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9206527) with the `Array` field, excluding the `[` and `]` characters:

- ***Chart (Community Visualisation)***: [CSV Filter Control](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/2b0a22a2-3992-49e1-be12-bdc22937daea/page/QPvLB)
- ***Column to Filter on***: `REGEXP_REPLACE(Array, R"(\]|\[)", "")`
- ***Interactions***: (Tick) Apply Filter
- ***Style Tab***: (Unchecked - default behaviour) OR instead of AND behaviour

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/31188884-8813-4b9f-bc18-a3d8ef0fc465) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KQLdE3UWdaz_HSS6DFoIU-4dVSspbUJZZvmpVpSSQZc/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]